# Current Location on iOS(5) simulator is Not working?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, core-location

I'm having a problem with location on simulator.

It is working when I run the app on my device but it does not work when I run it in the iOS(5) Simulator.

Any solution?

Comment: When you say it is not working, what do you mean? Does it keep giving you a location of 1 Infinite Loop? :-)

Comment: Thank you, I designed an app that should show me my current location. when i debug it on simulator, it does not work. it just shows me a blue background. but when i run it in my device , it's work and shows me my current location.

Answer (score 0):

Location services not working in simulator since 4. You can set current location latitude/longitude via Simulator menu -> Debug -> Location -> Custom location...

Comment: it was working with me before with iOS 5.I know how to custom location. but I need it to show my current location wherever I.

Comment: Starting somewhere from Xcode 4.1 Simulator was unable to show location (one of many discussions here https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3237581?start=0&tstart=0) and not working Location Service in Simulator as result.

Comment: Yes you are right , it was not working in Xcode 4.1 but I test it in Xcode 4.3 (iOS 5) and it was working with me but I do not know why it is stop. plz see http://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios5/

Comment: I see, I described steps for **Location simulation** in my first comment. Simulator won't work in other way, now this behavior is default for him.

Comment: But in my iOS 5 Simulator, "Location" menu item is disabled. Why?

Comment: Because I think you testing for iOS 4.3. That feature works for testing for iOS5